# Set minimum height to be the higher between x and screen height

Tags: html, css

I have a page with a repeated background image that I want to expand behind the entire page content.

So I want the HTML's height to be set to either 600px or 100% of screen—the highest between them

(600px being the minimum height I need for my content, and 100% in case that the screen height is bigger than 600px so I want to expand my HTML to fit it)

I tried

```
html
{
    min-height:600px;
    height:100%
}
```

which doesn't work.

The repeated `background-image` is in a nested div (`#container`) since my site's width is limited and centered

```
#container
{
    width:1000px;  
height: 100%;
margin:0 auto;
background-image: url("/images/bg_content.png");
}

<body>
  <div id="container">
  </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apply to the body, not the HTML

```
body { 
  min-height:600px; 
  height:100%;
}
```

This [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/LssZq/1/show/) will always have a minmum of 600px but will expand when required.

Comment: This works if the background-image is in the body, but I need it in a nested div. I edited my question with the details

Comment: So, I ended up adding min-height:600px to the #container and it worked fine... Thanks!